# setText state not clearing when submit is pressed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

The problem is this: When the user presses "submit" the `handleSubmit` function does two things 1) Adds the item to the array of todos, 2) Sets the TextInput to "" so that it would clear itself.

So it's basically focused on the single `AddTodo` component.

But why isn't it clearing ?

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  FlatList,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

import { Header } from "./components/header";
// import { AddTodo } from "./components/addTodo";
import { TodoItem, TodoItemProps } from "./components/todoItem";

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<TodoItemProps[]>([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  function pressHandler(id: string) {
    setTodos((prevTodos) => prevTodos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
  }

  function submitHandler(text: string) {
    setTodos((prevTodos) => [
      { text, id: Math.random().toString() },
      ...prevTodos,
    ]);
    setText("");
  }

  function handleChange(val: string) {
    setText(val);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <Text style={styles.info}>
          Write in the text input & submit to add them.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.info}>
          Double Click in the items to remove them.
        </Text>
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={todos}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TodoItem item={item} pressHandler={pressHandler} />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          />
        </View>
        <AddTodo
          handleSubmit={submitHandler}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          text={text}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

export function AddTodo({
  handleSubmit,
  handleChange,
  text,
}: {
  handleSubmit: (text: string) => void;
  handleChange: (val: string) => void;
  text: string;
}) {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Write New Todo"
        onChangeText={handleChange}
        value={text}
      />
      <Button
        title="Add Todo"
        onPress={() => handleSubmit(text)}
        color="coral"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  list: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 20,
  },
  info: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    padding: 20,
  },
  input: {
    margin: 20,
    padding: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "coral",
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with clearing the TextInput value after submission. Let's try this.

```
function submitHandler(text: string) {
  setTodos((prevTodos) => [
    { text, id: Math.random().toString() },
    ...prevTodos,
  ]);
  setText(""); // Clear the text state after adding todo
}

function handleChange(val: string) {
  setText(val); // Update the text state as the input changes
}
```

Comment: are you basically repeating my code? makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking at the rendered UI in a browser:**

- `onPress` needs to be handled with `e.preventDefault`.
- You can use `Platform` if you need to ID the device.
- For phones apps though you won't need to prevent the default.

```js
      <Button
        title="Add Todo"
        onPress={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          handleSubmit(text);
        }}
        color="coral"
      />
```